deciphering notation used by Jessop (Quartic Surfaces)
I am reading a rather famous work by Jessop "Quartic Surfaces with Singular Points". This is quite an old book published in 1916. I was wondering if someone could help me with a notation $\between$. I am not sure if this notation is outdated or if I am simply unaware of it. For instance, in the introduction of the book it already appears in the second page:

When a quartic surface is such that it has eight nodes consisting of
the common points of three quadrics, the tangent cone from any node to
the surface gives rise to a plane sextic of the first kind: such a
quartic surface is said to be syzygetic: the equation of the surface
is represented by an equation of the form $$(a\between A,B,C)^2 = 0$$
where $A=0,B=0, C=0$ represent quadrics whose intersections give the
eight nodes.

The term $a$ never appears in the book (and this happens in several ocassions in the book). Is this saying that the quartic surface belongs to the linear system generated by $A^2,B^2,C^2$ i.e. it is of the form $$\alpha A^2+\beta B^2 + \gamma C^2 $$
for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in the ground field (in Jessop's case I would assume characteristic $0$).

I've just had a quick look at Jessop. I think your guess is not far away. I think it means a linear combination of the products of two (not necessarily different) quadratic forms from $\{A,B,C\}$. So you will still have to add terms from the products $AB, AC$ and $BC$.
